# Optimizacion de Codigo

Tags: python, pandas

Soy nuevo en Python y en programación en general, necesito ayuda para realizar esta acción porque mi código funciona pero lo hace extremadamente lento.

Tengo que recorrer un DataFrame de Pandas en Python buscando cuantas veces aparece cada numero de teléfono de la columna "Teléfonos" en la misma columna, vale aclarar que el teléfono lo uso como ID de clientes. Entonces lo que realmente estoy buscando cuantas veces ese cliente esta en nuestros datos, y por ultimo si el numero esta repetido desecharlo del DataFrame El código que se me ocurrió es este:

```py
Comerciales["Aproximaciones cliente"]=0

for i in range(len(Comerciales)):
    print(i)
    numero=Comerciales.iloc[i,5]
    for j in range(len(Comerciales)):
        numero2=Comerciales.iloc[j,5]
        if numero==numero2:
            Comerciales.iloc[i,25]=Comerciales.iloc[i,25]+1
            if i!=j:
                Comerciales.iloc[j,5]=0
Comerciales=Comerciales.loc[(Comerciales["Teléfono"]!=0)]
Comerciales.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comerciales es el nombre del DataFrame, La columna 5 son los números de teléfono y la columna 25 es la que agrego arriba en donde guardo cuantas aproximaciones tuvo el cliente. [Link del csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/109Wd5hzJGBiSSAtRxMErD-myiDAjF4G_/view?usp=sharing)

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Los`for` nunca son buena opción para una *Dataframe*, mejor usa su método `.apply()`

Comment: Gracias ahora lo investigare

Comment: Mejor te doy una respuesta, vas a ver algunos conceptos diferentes y un poco complejos

Comment: Te lo agradecería muchísimo así puedo avanzar, y tu ejemplo me servirá para estudiarlo, pero de todas maneras lo investigare para mejorar mis próximos códigos, e igual muchas gracias :) :)

Comment: Podriß colocsr los dato? Así podre hacer el ejemplo lo más parecido posible

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/109Wd5hzJGBiSSAtRxMErD-myiDAjF4G_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Te los simplifique en 2 columnas, la prima son los telefonos que hay que buscar similitudes y la segunda debería remarcar cuantas veces ese telefono esta repetido

Comment: OK muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias a vos querido, ya la estoy investigando me has simplificado la vida muchisimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo bien tu csv, creo que es mejor agrupar los datos utilizando `groupby(campo)`. Utilizo esto por que así agrupamos los datos y ya no tendremos datos repetidos. A esta agrupación le podemos aplicar cualquier método como `sum()`, `mean()`, `count()`.

Para leer tu archivo vamos a tener un problema, pues pandas infiere el tipo de dato y la columna `Teléfono` es un numero, por lo que pandas lo tomará como un dato de tipo entero, para evitar eso podemos especificar el tipo de dato de la columna.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("Datos.csv",dtype={"Teléfono":str},index_col=0)

#agrupamos los datos segun el campo Teléfono y los contamos
df = df.groupby("Teléfono").count()
```

**resultado**

|  | Aproximaciones cliente |
| --- | --- |
| Teléfono |  |
| +5491122041932 | 1 |
| +5491143138147 | 1 |
| +5491158855952 | 1 |
| +5491159728440 | 1 |
| +5491159738610 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| +5493544579198 | 1 |
| +5493585097180 | 1 |
| +5493704508030 | 1 |
| +5493794699383 | 1 |
| +5493837495648 | 1 |

La columna `Teléfono` contendrá la contabilización de los datos que sean iguales, pero no solo será esta columna sino todas las que tengas.

Comment: Impecable Christian, muchísimas gracias, así lo hare